# How much should a unit test know about the function it is testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, caching, flask

I'm writing a test for a caching mechanism. The mechanism has two cache layers, the request cache and redis. The request cache uses `Flask.g`, an object that stores values for the duration of the request. It does this by creating a dictionary, on the `Flask.g._cache` attribute.

However, I think that the exact attribute is an implementation detail that my unit test shouldn't care about. I want to make sure it stores its values on Flask.g, but I don't care about how it does that. What would be a good way to test this?

I'm using the Python mock module, so I know I can mock out `Flask.g, but I'm not sure if there's a way to test whether there has been any property access on it, without caring about which property it is.

Is this even the right approach for tests like this?

Comment: Rather than looking at what the specifics of the *cache* are in your test, why not just ensure that `expensive_op_1` and `expensive_op_2` do *not* get called more than once?  Where the data is cached doesn't matter (as far as the test is concerned) - it's *whether* the data is cached and re-used rather than re-requested that you want to test.  (Or do I mis-understand your question?)

Comment: Well, the request cache is a lot quicker than going to redis.

Answer (score 0):

Personally you shouldn't be mocking Flask.g if you are testing endpoints. since you would be creating a self.app (I may be unsure about this portion)

Secondly you will need to mock the redis client with something like this being the returned structure.

```
class RedisTestCase(object):
    saved_dictionary = {}
    def keys(self, pattern):
        found_keys = []
        for key in RedisTestCase.saved_dictionary: #loop keys for pattern
            if pattern:
                found_keys.append(key)
        return found_keys

    def delete(self, keys):
        for key in keys:
            if key in RedisTestCase.saved_dictionary:
                del RedisTestCase.saved_dictionary[key]

    def mset(self, items):
        RedisTestCase.saved_dictionary.update(items)

    def pipeline(self):
        return RedisTestCase()
```